# Changing to an Error Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to validate the length of a string in the inputbox. If the string is invalid it will trigger an onblur event.   When this event is triggered, it must turn the label of the object associated with the trigger red.  However, there is a css class that exist that contains the style, so I just need to change the class to that class.
The prefix is some value being passed in.
Here is sample code.

```
var input = $(this).val();
var findLabel = document.getElementById`enter code here`(prefix+'findLabel');
if(input.length < min || input.length > max){
    //alert is to check the values for testing
   alert('Value for selected country '+selectedCountry+' must be between '+min+' and '+max+' characters');
}
```

example

```
<div class="Value_s123" id="a1Values123" style="float:left;">
    <span class="avalue" id="a1value">
        <label class="classOff" id="a1ValueLabel">some value</label>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input id="a1CatchValue" maxlength="15" name="a1Value" onblur="requiredFieldValidation(&#34;a1Postal&#34;)" size="15" tabindex="13" type="text"><img alt="Required" height="9" id="a1ValueReqdImg" src="/img/icn_dia.gif" width="11">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I need to get the a1ValueLabel  and the class classOff and turn it to classON

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#a1ValueLabel").removeClass("classOff").addClass("classOn");
```

Comment: Dif(postalEventStarter.length < min || postalEventStarter.length > max){
       
       alert('The postal code for '+selectedCountry+' must be between '+min+' and '+max+' characters');
       if(!$("#"+prefix+"PostalLabel").hasClass('classOn')){                
 $(document).trigger("rif_Invid_PostalCode", this);
 else

Comment: I need for a trigger to work also, but it will not work with the code.

Comment: EX $(document).trigger("rif_Invid_PostalCode", this); else $(document).trigger("rif_Valid_PostalCode", this);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.  The script is run every time someone types, once it reaches more than 5 characters the script adds the class "classOn" to the label tag.  If there are 5 or less characters, it removes the "classOn" and adds the "classOff" class.

This is not a sustainable way to do it however, if you wanted to run this script on multiple items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a1CatchValue').on('keyup',function(){
        if ($(this).val().length > 5) {
            $('#a1ValueLabel').removeClass('classOff');
            $('#a1ValueLabel').addClass('classOn');
        }
        else {
            $('#a1ValueLabel').removeClass('classOn');
            $('#a1ValueLabel').addClass('classOff');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.